# AdMob: Ads not working with my package name

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services, google-ads-api, adsense

I have a problem implementing AdMob with my Android app, ads are not showing for my package name, I changed the name and everything works fine, I restored the prod name and everything stopped working with the error: no ad config, this is my first time using AdMob, which means the ads work for a while and then suddenly stop is not the case here, I don't suspect anything wrong with the code because I followed everything in the documentation and, as I said, everything works fine when I change the package name to a random string.

1. Is app-ads.txt correct? yes, app-ads.txt file found and verified (100% of queries authorized)
2. Policy center: no current issues, no disapproved apps
3. App linked to admob? yes it is linked through google play and I noticed the icon is updated
4. PIN verification: I still didn't reach the verification threshold
5. Is Google Ads and Adsense linked to Admob? yes, and with the same email
6. Admob status: Your account is approved
7. App approval status: Ready (Ad serving enabled)
8. App stores: Google Play
9. Ad format: Rewarded
10. Ads activity performance, Requests: 0 (ZERO)

Note 1: the email I am using on play console is diff from the email of admob / ads / adsense

Note 2: the prod app is already launched in google play store

Any help guys?

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.admob;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.LoadAdError;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.OnUserEarnedRewardListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.RequestConfiguration;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.InitializationStatus;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.OnInitializationCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.rewarded.RewardItem;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.rewarded.RewardedAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.rewarded.RewardedAdLoadCallback;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RewardedAd mRewardedAd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /**/
        RequestConfiguration configuration = new RequestConfiguration.Builder().setTestDeviceIds(Arrays.asList("PEO7WS709MHDMHS0KA74LQ4KDPL9V8DJ")).build();
        /**/
        MobileAds.setRequestConfiguration(configuration);
        /**/

        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
            }
        });

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

        RewardedAd.load(this, "ca-app-pub-2887021452579791/7518976046",
                adRequest, new RewardedAdLoadCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                        // Handle the error.
                        Log.d(TAG, loadAdError.getMessage());
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, loadAdError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        mRewardedAd = null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull RewardedAd rewardedAd) {
                        mRewardedAd = rewardedAd;
                        Log.d(TAG, "Ad was loaded.");
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Ad was loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mRewardedAd != null) {
                    Activity activityContext = MainActivity.this;
                    mRewardedAd.show(activityContext, new OnUserEarnedRewardListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onUserEarnedReward(@NonNull RewardItem rewardItem) {
                            // Handle the reward.
                            Log.d(TAG, "The user earned the reward.");
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onUserEarnedReward", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "The rewarded ad wasn't ready yet.");
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Not ready!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });


    }
}
```

Manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.admob">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AdMob">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-2887021452579791~7783129272"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: how old us your admob account

Comment: maybe between 15 days and a month, not sure

Answer (score 0):

AdMob uses some time to observe your traffic. It may take 1-2 weeks to show ads or even more in some cases.

Comment: I knew that time can fix a lot of things, but I didn't expect it to be able to fix admob too, the bad thing about this is that google returns the same error for multiple issues, which makes debugging a bit difficult if you googled the admob community about the error: no ad config, they will give you 10 or 20 tasks to check in order to fix the problem, I think it doesn't hurt to return "app-ads.txt file is missing" or "your app was not approved, you can't receive ads" instead of "no ad config"

Comment: if test ads are showing then all you can do is wait

Comment: this is the problem even the test ads are not showing, I am using the app ID in the manifest, the unit ID when making the AdRequest and the test ID I got from the logcat, nothing still: no ad config!

Comment: can you share your project

Comment: I updated the post, take a look please

Comment: Now the code I posted use the package name: com.example.admob which is just an example to check if everything works or not, if I keep the same code and edit the package name from gradle I get no ad config

Comment: are banner and interestial ads showing

Comment: I haven't tested this actually, I'll try it now, I think the ad unit needs about 1 hour to be ready to show ads, I'll try in a moment

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue with you. Ads only show after I renamed to a random package id. After I switched back to my original id, it always return error "No Ad Config". Have you found a solution ?

Comment: Does you find any solution?